# Change PHP version in IIS 6

Tags: php, iis, iis-6, php-5.3, php-5.2

Trying to upgrade from PHP 5.2.5 to 5.2.17 (and then to 5.3.6 once that works) on IIS 6.0, installing the language itself runs just fine and I changed the PHP.ini/ect locations that IIS uses for PHP, everything still works but when I run PHP info on my site it still says it's running PHP 5.2.5. Restarted IIS, restarted the server even, no difference. What do I do to change which version/what location of PHP IIS is using?

When I install PHP 5.3.6 the site no longer works, so I know installing different versions is doing SOMETHING, but I think it might only be changing the PHP.ini my server is using, not the version of PHP.

In addition to installing the windows binary release of PHP I've also tried installing PHP from Microsoft's Web Platform Installer (both 5.3.6 and 5.2.17), after installing neither showed up as the current version in phpinfo either.

Comment: don't know iis but have you try to follow a tutorial : http://blogs.iis.net/donraman/archive/2009/10/08/upgrading-to-php-5-3-an-easy-way.aspx ?

Comment: To upgrade PHP 5.2.5 to 5.2.17: 1) Stop IIS completely (or stop websites that use PHP and restart IIS); 2) Install new PHP version into the same locations -- you can just copy new files over replacing all old files .. but better remove all old files first (except .ini file maybe); 3) If you are using some non-standard php extensions then you may need to update them as well; 4) Resume IIS. This always worked well for me.

Comment: If upgrading from 5.2 to 5.3 -- that's a different story. I do not know how you run 5.2 (quite possible ISAPI mode), but 5.3 can only run via FastCGI. In ISAPI mode you need to use thread-safe build while in FastCGI is has to be NON-thread safe. This is one more point to check. In any case -- when doing this sort of upgrade disable ALL non bundled extensions until you make this simple code work: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`. When done -- enable extensions and check again. If works -- try your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use php 5.3, you must install IIS FastCGI extension and run PHP as cgi script. From php 5.3 isapi is not supported. But everything works fine if you configure it, and as benefit you can use more php version simultaneously. IIS 6 is not a problem. Download PHP non thread safe.

For details see this, for example: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/247/using-fastcgi-to-host-php-applications-on-iis-60/

Comment: Great to know this is possible, though as my answer shares, I've moved on. Hopefully anyone else finding this question will find it useful :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Download the latest VC11 x86 Non Thread Safe version of PHP from http://windows.php.net/download/
2. Once the zip is downloaded, right click on the zip file and select properties.  Make sure you unblock the file.
3. Rename your current PHP folder to PHPold.
4. Find your php.ini file and rename it to phpold.ini
5. Extract the zip file to c:\temp\php.
6. Copy the php folder from c:\temp to wherever your old PHP folder was.
7. Go to your new php folder and copy php.ini-production and paste it to where your old php.ini file was
8. Rename php.ini-production to php.ini
9. On the server, make sure you have Notepad++ along with the Compare plugin.  If you need the compare plugin, use these steps.  http://www.davidtan.org/how-to-compare-two-text-files-using-notepad-plus/
10. In the location that stores your phpold.ini and php.ini, right click on each of those files and open them with Notepad++.  On the php.ini, only make changes to the lines with the >> next to them.
11. Once the changes have been made, make sure you save php.ini.
12. Go to Services and restart IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Solution has been to move to Apache in my case. IIS 7 has better tools but IIS has proven to be a poor environment for development in this case.